# Adding extra file properties to each file on the client and read all the file properties from the request object on the server

Tags: angular, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi, file-attributes, multiple-file-upload

```
private CertificateAttachement AssignAttachmentValues()
    {
        CertificateAttachement resourceCertificateAttachment = new CertificateAttachement();
        byte[] fileByte;
        foreach (var file in Request.Form.Files)
        {
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    file.CopyTo(ms);
                    fileByte = ms.ToArray();
                    resourceCertificateAttachment.DocumentMimeType = file.ContentType;
                    resourceCertificateAttachment.DocumentContent = fileByte;
                    resourceCertificateAttachment.DocumentName = file.FileName;
                    ms.Close();
                }
            }
        }
        return resourceCertificateAttachments;
    }
```

This is the code in WebAPI for reading the file properties in the controller. How can the extra properties for each file can be added on the client side and read on the server side. Is there an in-built way to do that.... ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `FormData` in client side, something like this:

```
uploadFile(file: File,docId:number): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('upload', file);
    formData.append('docId', String(docId));
    let params = new HttpParams();
    const options = {params: params};
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', "yourUrl", formData, options);
    return this.http.request(req);
  }
```

and on your dotnet API side, you can get all the files along with passed parameters.

```
 public HttpResponseMessage UploadDocs()
    {
        var PostedParamValues = HttpContext.Current.Request.Form;
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Files.Count == 0)
        {
            //No files found
        }
        var file = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;//all files
        var data = PostedParamValues.AllKeys // all parameters passed

        foreach (string kvp in PostedParamValues.AllKeys)
        {
            var value = PostedParamValues[kvp];//getting the values of param passed
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Files uploaded");
    }
```